# Setting executable icon in Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, embedded-resource

I'm rather unfamiliar with programming tools in Windows but have been forced to use VC++ 2010 Express for a project recently. We have been working on a piece of software that we didn't start and now we are reaching the finish line. Only problem is that I want to be able to set the executable icon.

Since the project is written mostly in SDL we have set the titlebar icon using the SDL_WM_SetIcon call as recommende on several sites but I still can't find any references to how to set the executable icon. All my google searches has turned up results about Visual Studio 2010 and Visual C++ 2008, neither of which seems appicable.

Answer (score 2):

Since VC++ 2010 Express lacks resource editor but not resource compiler this can be done by manually creating a resource.rc file in the project directory (same as where your .vcxproj files are located), also drop in your .ico version of your icon in the same directory.

In resource.rc add the following line:

```
IDI_APP  ICON  "icon.ico"
```

And add the file, in VC++, to the Resource Files.

Doing this in VC++ should result in something like this to be added to your .vcxproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ResourceCompile Include="resource.rc" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And to your vcxproj.filters:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ResourceCompile Include="resource.rc">
    <Filter>Resource Files</Filter>
  </ResourceCompile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation recently with the Express edition.

I came up with a different way to approach this (see gif).

Posting it here in case someone runs into similar problem.

[image]